# Making call to Google Cloud Natural Language API using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to form my request to Google's Cloud Natural Language API based on this code https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/reference/rest/v1/documents in Swift, but I can't quite get the syntax right?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class GoogleNaturalLanguageParser {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var googleAPIKey = "XXX"
    var googleURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=\(googleAPIKey)")!
    }
    //TODO: Add document 

    private func createRequest(with text: String, handler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        // Create our request URL

        var request = URLRequest(url: googleURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

          // Build our API request
    let jsonRequest = [
        "requests": [
        ["encodingType": "UTF8",
            "document": [
                "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
                "content": text
            ]
        ]
        ]

    ]
        let jsonObject = JSON(jsonDictionary: jsonRequest)
        //let jsonObject = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonRequest, options: []) as? [String : Any]

        // Serialize the JSON
        guard let data = try? jsonObject.rawData() else {
            return
        }

        request.httpBody = data



        // Run the request on a background thread
        DispatchQueue.global().async { self.runRequestOnBackgroundThread(request, handler: { (result) in
            handler(result)
        }) }

    }


}
```

Comment: Since you're getting a 404, a good way to debug this is to actually dump the URL you're forming and compare it to the one you're trying to form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're calling the vision API in your base URL. You should be calling the Natural Language API, not vision:

`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/documents:annotateText?key=\(googleAPIKey)`

Then, it depends on what you are trying to do i.e. sentiment, entities, or syntax analysis. As there is no iOS client lib, you'll have to handroll the request yourself (as you've already identified). Hopefully, the official docs have enough to get you going:

**Sentiment:**

Protocol [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-sentiment). For example:

https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSentiment?key=

```
{
  "encodingType": "UTF8",
  "document": {
    "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
    "content": "Enjoy your vacation!"
  }
}
```

**Entities:**

Protocol [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities). For example:

https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=

```
{
  "encodingType": "UTF8",
  "document": {
    "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
    "content": "President Obama is speaking at the White House."
  }
}
```

**Syntax:**

Protocol [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-syntax). For example:

https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSyntax?key=

```
{
  "encodingType": "UTF8",
  "document": {
    "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
    "content": "Hello, world!"
  }
}
```

Swift 3.0 equivalent would be something like this:

```
let jsonObject: [String:Any] = [
    "document": [
        "type": "PLAIN_TEXT",
        "content": "Michelangelo Caravaggio, Italian painter, is known for the Calling of Saint Matthew."],
        "encodingType": "UTF8"
]
```

Comment: The code you posted is for the Cloud Vision API which they have a Swift sample project for, they don't have Swift code for the Natural Language API that I posted in my question.

Comment: @GarySabo - yup, you're right. I'll see if I can find an example for NL, and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Appreciate it!  I just am having a hard time converting the sample Python to Swift

Comment: Ok, I updated my question based on your code...I'm trying to pass in text to Google and get back only English Words or names, so I think I want entities....however with the code I posted i'm still getting null on my response so I don't think I'm forming the request correctly still?

Comment: @GarySabo - what error are you seeing? Why are you calling `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/documents:*annotateText*`? Shouldn't it be (according to the docs) `https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:*analyzeEntities*?key=`....

Comment: Good catch, fixed that in my question...but still getting a `status code: 404, headers` when I print the response

Comment: @GarySabo - you're still calling the vision API! `https://-->vision<--.googleapis.com/v1`

Comment: my bad, ok calling the correct API now but same 404 headers response

Comment: thanks again, added my jsonObject to the bottom of your answer for anyone else that comes across this.